# sometimes when I press the button it works sometimes it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

**Problem:**

I want to develop a project using React and Firebase. But when the button is pressed by the react it is sometimes added. Sometimes the button does not work. What is the reason of this? I think it's an error in coding, but I don't know what the error is.

---

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import db from '../Firebase';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  username: '',
  email: '',
  password: ''
};

export class index extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {...INITIAL_STATE};
  }

  onSubmit = () => {
    const{ username, password, email} = this.state;
    db.collection('users').add({
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
      'email': email
    })
    .then(function(docRef) {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", username);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    const{ username, password, email} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>sign up</h2>
        <div className='container'>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input type='text' 
                  className='form-control mt-2' 
                  placeholder='username' 
                  name='username'
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={username}
                  />
            <input type='email' 
                  className='form-control mt-2' 
                  placeholder='email' 
                  name='email'
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={email}
                  />
            <input type='text' 
                  className='form-control mt-2' 
                  placeholder='password' 
                  name='password'
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={password}
                  />
            <button type='submit' 
                    className='btn btn-dark bg-dark btn-block mt-4'
                    >SIGN UP
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>       
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default index;
```

---

**Firebase/index.js**

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  databaseURL: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***"
})

var db = firebase.firestore();
export default db;
```

---

The codes are as shown above. There are "username", "password" and "email" fields on the page. With each change, the function "onChange" works and updates the "state" field. When the button is pressed, it sends the information to the "firebase" database (that's exactly the problem. It weren't send in database.).

Comment: Can you see the error message in the console or is it failing silently?

Comment: @MattAft there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you call `event.preventDefault()` in your `onSubmit` handler? Writing it like this:

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //  your existing code here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state implementation is kinda faulty.
Try to console the states inside the submit function, 
Does the fire base function produce any error?